# Upload binary files using jquery and Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to upload files to a Web server, using JQuery and Spring.
The web server is Tomcat.
This works well with text files, but not with binary files.
Uploading JPG or PDF, for example, produces larger files that cannot be opened.
I created a very simple web page just to demonstrate the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function upload() {
            var post_data = new FormData();    
            post_data.append( 'file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/rest/api/events/',
                cache: false,
                data: post_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            });  
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <button id='uploadBtn' onclick='upload();'>Upload</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/events")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
@ResponseBody
Object addEvent(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        file.transferTo(new File("C:\\" + file.getOriginalFilename()));
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
    }
    return "";
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to find the problem. My code is fine (you can use it as a sample for ultra-simple file upload tests...), however there was an XSS filter in the application, which changed the encoding to UTF-8. Removing this filter for multipart requests solved the problem.